# How to project multiple images onto a single object

Tags: texturing, modifiers, uv, objects, camera

How do you project multiple images onto a single object? I have tried some things but it never worked. I have tried to search for it online but to no success and with my current skill level I am not able to come up with a viable solution. Under here you see an example of something I'm trying to make.

[image: Audio equipment from textures.com]

As you see I will need to project three images onto an object but I don't know-howbj. Maybe there is another smarter way and a better workflow. Any suggestion will be gladly appreciated

Comment: I don't think I will be able to successfully use this method. I'm looking for a more straight-up method since this seems to need a lot of tweaking to get it right

Comment: Okay, sure :). Perhaps UV projection could be used for this. Something like this? https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/165123/78972

Comment: This works! Thank you for helping

Comment: Glad to hear that :). If you get stuck somewhere, feel free to ask a new question. Good luck.